# According to ONE, who would win in a fight between Tatsumaki and Mob?

Tags: one-punch-man, mob-psycho-100

While browsing through [**tvtropes**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/MobPsycho100), I found the following thing:

> The Verse: ONE has implied this and One-Punch Man share a verse **(He was asked and answered a question on who would win between Mob and Tatsumaki from said series)**.

Emphasis mine.

Unfortunately, tvtropes does not elaborate on this any further. There are no links or sources pointing to the discussion mentioned, and now I am very curious to know what answer ONE gave.

According to ONE, if Tatsumaki and Mob were to fight, who would win?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [One Punch Man Wiki](http://onepunchman.wikia.com/wiki/Tatsumaki) at the Tatsumaki page, it is stated :

> ONE has said that Tatsumaki is stronger than 100% Mob, the protagonist of ONE's other work, Mob Psycho 100, but against ???% Mob, there's no answer.

Still according to [One Punch Man Wiki](http://onepunchman.wikia.com/wiki/Interviews#Niconico_Interview.5B2.5D), ONE said this during  his Niconico interview.

Answer (score 1):

ONE: Tatsumaki in her best shape could've defeated Golden Sperm. Golden Sperm is equally strong as ossan (main protagonist from makai no ossan). Tatsumaki is stronger than Normal Mob, if he gets serious, there's no answer.

Normal Mob = Tatsumaki Win

Serious Mob (100%) = Too close to call

???% Mob = Mob

Current Mob (Up to 500%) = Mob